# Constructing a complete measure space

Tags: measure-theory

Working on the following proposition in Royden:

Proposition: If $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ is a measure space, then we can find a complete measure space (one that contains all subsets of sets of measure zero) $(X,\mathcal{B}_0,\mu_0)$ such that:

1. $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{B}_0$
2. $E\in\mathcal{B}$ implies $\mu E=\mu_0 E$
3. $E\in\mathcal{B}_0$ if and only if $E=A\cup B$ where $A\in\mathcal{B}$ and $B\subset C$, $C\in\mathcal{B}$, $\mu C=0$.

I've managed to show that $\mathcal{B_0}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{B}$. I've managed to define $\mu_0$ on $\mathcal{B}_0$ so that $\mu_0 E=\mu E$ for all $E\in\mathcal{B}$.

I am currently stuck on the last part, showing that $\mathcal{B_0}$ is complete. I start by letting $A\cup B\in \mathcal{B}_0$ with $\mu_0(A\cup B)=0$. Note that this means $A\in \mathcal{B}$ and $B\subset C\in\mathcal{B}$, $\mu C=0$. Next, I let $E\subset A\cup B$.

What I've been unable to show is that $E\in\mathcal{B}_0$, which would complete my proof.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

$\mu(U\cup G)=0$ because $\mu(U)+\mu(G) \geq \mu(U\cup G)$,$ 0=\overline{\mu}(F)=\mu(U)$ and $\mu(G)=0$.$\overline{\mu}(F)=\mu(U)$ by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Nice and slow.

We need to show that if $E\subset X$ with $E\subset F$, $F\in B_0$ and $\overline{\mu}(F)=0$ then $E\in B_0$  and $\overline{\mu}(E)=0$. Where $\overline{\mu}$ is the extension of $\mu$ to the algebra $B_0$.

Assume that $E\subset X$ and $E\subset F$, with $F\in B_0$ and $\overline{\mu}(F)=0$.

Then $F=U\cup V$ with $U\in B$ $V\subset G\in B$ with $\mu(G)=0$. Since $0=\overline{\mu}(F)=\mu(V)$ we get that $F\subset U\cup G$ and $\mu(U\cup G)=0$. So $E$ is a subset of a set $K\in B$ of $\mu$ measure zero. By definition of $B_0$, $E=\emptyset\cup E\in B_0$.

Now take $E$ and $K\setminus E$. Then $0=\mu(K)=\overline{\mu}(E)+\overline{\mu}(G\setminus E)\geq \overline{\mu}(E)\geq 0$. Therefore $\overline{\mu}(E)=0$.

Comment: Using these characters and the hypotheses set up, I believe what is needed is to prove that $E\in B_0$, which I don't see that this is saying.

Comment: There was a typo. Instead of $E\in B_0$ at the beginning it should have been $E\subset X$.

Comment: Nope, still a problem. You have $E=\phi\cup E$. To show that this is an element in $B_0$, you have to show that $\phi\in B$ (which is true) and $E\in B_0$, which hasn't been shown. $F\in B_0$ and $E\subset F$ does not necessarily mean that $E\in B$.

Comment: The definition of $B_0$ is sets of the form $A\cup E$ with $A\in B$ and $E\subset U\in B$ with $\mu(U)=0$. Your last sentence hasn't been used in the proof.

Comment: In your latest proof, why is $\mu(U\cup G)=0$?